# Creating a colorwheel with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, algorithm

I'm trying to figure out a way to create a colorwheel similar to this:[image], in JS. The colorwheel should have ~4096<sup>(*)</sup> elements the size of a single pixel, with their color set via a CSS `background` rule.

*I know this is not how you're supposed to create a colorpicker, and that normally you should never have so many single-pixel DOM elements for anything. **You don't need to tell this to me or try to figure out a different way to accomplish this.***

I'd also be interested in having each of the pixel-sized elements be left-aligned, instead of for example absolutely-positioned.

*<sup>(x)</sup>: 4096 is the number of all shorthand HEX codes (#XXX), but the colorwheel doesn't have monochrome values, except for white. So the actual number of unique colors would be 4081(?)*

---

This is the code I've managed to come up with (pretty much nothing):

```
var p = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
for(var i = 0; i < p.length; i++)
{
    for(var j = 0; j < p.length; j++)
    {
        for(var k = 0; k < p.length; k++)
        {
            document.write('<div style="background:#' + p[i] + p[j] + p[k] +'"></div>');
        }
    }
}
```

And [image] is the result I get (zoomed 10x), with the following CSS:

```
div
{
    float: left;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}
```

As you can see, it's pretty far from what I want. So any help would be greatly appreciated, since I'm quite lost on how to accomplish this. I've got the colors, but I don't know how to arrange them in a wheel.

---

**EDIT:**
Unless someone happens to give me a pretty much complete solution to this, it seems that this is a bit above my skill-level, at the moment. So I'm willing to settle for something that (I assume) would be easier to implement.

Basically another form of output that would be acceptable, would be something like this: [image]

Comment: Currently my code (as I noted) doesn't accomplish much. It's just 3 nested loops that will output all the colors I want (#000 - #fff). The problem I'm facing is converting this code to something that will give me what I want. So the current output is technically generating what I want, just not in the right order/form.

Comment: I deleted my comment because I previously hadn't seen the image of what you want the end result to be.  Unless your trigonometry is very strong I'd give up on this idea and simply use something that exists.  I know you don't want to do that, but it's the most sensible idea.

Comment: I won't give up, in the hopes that someone with better trigonometry than me finds this question :)

Comment: First, I'll leave a link to an MDN page that implements a colour-picker. They simply use an image and then retrieve the colour of the pixel under the cursor. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas Next, I'll point out that the 3rd image is dead-easy to create and requires no math. How so? Easy, the browser can work with both the RGB and the HSL colour-spaces. That image simple has hue varying from 0 to 360 (degrees) from left to right, with sat and lum changing in the y-axis. sat=0, lum=100 at the top, sat=100,lum=0 at the bottom.

Comment: @user6003859 - I've just realized something important. While I had chosen the HSL colour model as a tool to create the wheel/strip images, this, while being better than the RGB model, is still not the best choice. If one is to choose the HSV model, it's a very simple matter of interpolating the 3 values before feeding them into a hsv2rgb function. I'll throw something together, that allows you to choose either the wheel or the strip (they're virtually identical, the math required is very similar - the wheel simply needs a cartesian --> polar coordinate transform)

Comment: @user6003859 - answer updated. Hope this helps explain better what's going on. :)

Answer (score 4):

I had previously posted an answer that relied upon the browser converting a colour from the HSL colour-space to the RGB one. Unfortunately, this was an approach that while simple, didn't produce the images shown.

In order to correctly produce the desired outputs, a far easier method is to instead utilise the HSV colour model - one which is quite similar to the HSL one.

When we use the correct colour-space, determining the correct colour for any given pixel is a simple matter of interpolating 3 values - all of which change linearly (the amount of change remains constant. 0 at one end, 1 at the other end will mean 0.5 at a point half-way between them)

First, lets look at your desired outputs and how our HSV inputs change with respect to X and Y coordinates. We'll start of with the easier to visualise and create - the flat strip.

**Flat strip**

[image]

We can observe the following about this image:

1. The hue ranges from 0 at the left edge to 360 at the right edge.
2. The sat ranges from 0 at the top edge to 1, half-way between the top
   & bottom edges. Beyond the point it reaches 1, it's clamped to 1.
3. The val ranges from 0 half-way between the top and bottom to 1 at
   the bottom.  Before the point it is 0, it's clamped to 0.

Now, let's look at the wheel representation of the same picture.

**Colour wheel**

[image]
If you look closely, you'll see that the strip, when wrapped into a circle will produce the colour-wheel. The centre of the wheel corresponds to the top-edge of the strip and the outer edge corresponds to the bottom edge.

This is also how we can show that the original wheel you showed is a somewhat innacurate representation of the colour-space, since it has the red on the left edge. Basically, your image has been flipped horizontally. ;)

Okay, that then shows how the images are related to the HSV colour-space. Next, we really need to be able to create them on the fly. This is fairly straight-forward now we've the plan for how to go about it.

Once this is done, we'll end up with 2 canvases - these were the images I used for the annotations. From there, there's a couple of ways you could go about it.
You could: allow the user to pick any colour they like, before returning to them the closest colour from the set of short-hand hex values.
Or you could: back-up a little, only setting colours on the canvas to those which are in the same set of short-hand values.

One will take longer to calculate the chosen colour, while the other will take longer to calculate the initial images.

I have left that part of the implementation up to you, instead opting to: eschew the idea of so many DOM elements, using just 2 canvas instead and also, to simply pick the colour exactly as chosen, based off the code I linked to @ MDN.

```js
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag)}

window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);
function onDocLoaded(evt)
{
 var strip = makeCanvas();
 strip.addEventListener('mousemove', pick);
 document.body.appendChild( strip );

 var wheel = makeWheel(256);
 wheel.addEventListener('mousemove', pick);
 document.body.appendChild( wheel );
}


var hsv2rgb = function(hsv) {
  var h = hsv.hue, s = hsv.sat, v = hsv.val;
  var rgb, i, data = [];
  if (s === 0) {
    rgb = [v,v,v];
  } else {
    h = h / 60;
    i = Math.floor(h);
    data = [v*(1-s), v*(1-s*(h-i)), v*(1-s*(1-(h-i)))];
    switch(i) {
      case 0:
        rgb = [v, data[2], data[0]];
        break;
      case 1:
        rgb = [data[1], v, data[0]];
        break;
      case 2:
        rgb = [data[0], v, data[2]];
        break;
      case 3:
        rgb = [data[0], data[1], v];
        break;
      case 4:
        rgb = [data[2], data[0], v];
        break;
      default:
        rgb = [v, data[0], data[1]];
        break;
    }
  }
  return rgb;
};

function clamp(min, max, val)
{
 if (val < min) return min;
 if (val > max) return max;
 return val;
}

function makeCanvas()
{
 var can, ctx;
 can = newEl('canvas');
 ctx = can.getContext('2d');
 can.width = 360;
 can.height = 100;
 var span = newEl('span');
 
 var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,360,100);
 var xPos, yPos, index;
 var height=imgData.height, width=imgData.width;
 
 
 for (yPos=0; yPos<height; yPos++)
 {
  for (xPos=0; xPos<width; xPos++)
  {
   // this is the point at which the S & V values reach
            // the peaks or start to change. 2 means height/2
            // so a divisor of 3 would mean the 'break-points'
            // were at the 1/3 and 2/3 positions
            // while a divisor of 4 would imply 1/4 and 3/4
            //
            // Have a look at the generated images using the eye- 
            // dropper tool of an image program (Gimp, Photoshop,
            // etc) that allows you to choose the HSV colour
            // model, to get a better idea of what I'm saying
            // here.
            var divisor = 2;

   var hue = xPos;
   var sat = clamp(0, 1, yPos / (height/divisor) );
   var val = clamp(0, 1, (height-yPos) / (height/divisor) );
   var rgb = hsv2rgb( {hue:hue, sat:sat, val:val} );
   
   index = 4 * (xPos + yPos*360);
   
            imgData.data[ index + 0 ] = rgb[0] * 255; // r
   imgData.data[ index + 1 ] = rgb[1] * 255; // g
   imgData.data[ index + 2 ] = rgb[2] * 255; // b
   imgData.data[ index + 3 ] = 255; // a
  }
 }
 ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
 return can;
}

// see the comment in the above function about the divisor. I've
// hard-coded it here, to 2
// diameter/2 corresponds to the max-height of a strip image
function makeWheel(diameter)
{
 var can = newEl('canvas');
 var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
 can.width = diameter;
 can.height = diameter;
 var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,diameter,diameter);
 var maxRange = diameter / 2;
 
 for (var y=0; y<diameter; y++)
 {
  for (var x=0; x<diameter; x++)
  {
   var xPos = x - (diameter/2);
   var yPos = (diameter-y) - (diameter/2);
   
   
   var polar = pos2polar( {x:xPos, y:yPos} );
   var sat = clamp(0,1,polar.len / ((maxRange/2)));
   var val = clamp(0,1, (maxRange-polar.len) / (maxRange/2) );
   
   var rgb = hsv2rgb( {hue:polar.ang, sat:sat, val:val} );
   
   var index = 4 * (x + y*diameter);
   imgData.data[index + 0] = rgb[0]*255;
   imgData.data[index + 1] = rgb[1]*255;
   imgData.data[index + 2] = rgb[2]*255;
   imgData.data[index + 3] = 255;
  }
 }
 ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0,0);
 return can;
}

function deg2rad(deg)
{
 return (deg / 360) * ( 2 * Math.PI );
}
function rad2deg(rad)
{
 return (rad / (Math.PI * 2)) * 360;
}

function pos2polar(inPos)
{
 var vecLen = Math.sqrt( inPos.x*inPos.x + inPos.y*inPos.y );
 var something = Math.atan2(inPos.y,inPos.x);
 while (something < 0)
  something += 2*Math.PI;
  
 return { ang: rad2deg(something), len: vecLen };
}



function pick(event) 
{
 var can = this;
 var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
 var color = document.getElementById('color');
 
  var x = event.layerX;
  var y = event.layerY;
  var pixel = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1);
  var data = pixel.data;
  var rgba = 'rgba(' + data[0] + ',' + data[1] +
             ',' + data[2] + ',' + (data[3] / 255) + ')';
  color.style.background =  rgba;
  color.textContent = rgba;
}
```

```css
canvas
{
 border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<div id="color" style="width: 200px; height: 50px; float: left;"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a great answer for pointing me in the right direction, and it has a lot of useful code for me. But regarding the part of my question where I specifically _**emphasize**_ the fact that there is no need to figure out another way (e.g. using a canvas instead of the DOM elements), you've quite annoyingly made your answer a bit incomplete. Granted, that could be regarded as a semi-minor implementation detail, but this in addition to the fact that the results your code produce don't include _only_ shorthand hex, means that I won't be marking this answer as accepted (at least yet).

Comment: You're welcome - that was precisely my aim. I consider your request for the DOM approach unreasonable and, without an iota of justification given for it, one I was unwilling to bother with. I didn't bother to "come up with" a different way of doing it - I refused to try to cajole DOM elements in the way you spoke of. Given the fact you're still using `document.write` and have the temerity to speak with an air of entitlement while complaining that my answer didn't give you exactly what you want and in which manner, I don't care if you accept it or not. The aim was your learning, not my points.

Comment: I only revisited the question today because I found it interesting and how to create the color-strip and color-wheel had been bugging me. You were always going to need a turn-key solution or would be scratching your head wondering how it worked. Your lack of response to the last answer all but confirmed this. Your comment this evening while dissapointing, is not a surprise. Suck-it-up kiddo. I want lots of things and am glad to receive those that are given to me, regardless of whether they are a perfect fit for my needs or not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are mapping a three-axis system (R, G, B) on a two-axis system (x,y). In the colorwheel example the three axis are drawn like a circle, and it is very difficult to create this using only x and y coördinates, especially when the requirement is that the pixels (div's) should be left-aligned.

The best approach to accomplish this is to create a three-dimensional array with the color values, map this onto a two-dimensional array and then loop this two-dimensional array from left to right and top-down.

Like this:

```
var p = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
for(var i = 0; i < p.length; i++)
{
    for(var j = 0; j < p.length; j++)
    {
        for(var k = 0; k < p.length; k++)
        {
            var x = i - k * 0.5;
            var y = j - k * 0.25;
            background[x][y] = "#" + p[i] + p[j] + p[k];
        }
    }
}

for (var l = 0; l < maxX; l++)
{
    for (var m = 0; m < maxY; m++)
    {
        document.write('<div style="background:#' + background[x][y] +'"></div>');
    }
}
```

This is not a complete answer, just a possible first step to solve this. Maybe this can help you to create a good solution.

Comment: Hmm, it does seem that the math required to do this is currently a bit beyond what I'm willing or able to put into this. I'll update my question with another result that would satisfy my needs.