CSS/SVG/Canvas: Dynamic / Moving Gradient
I was looking into ways to create a div with a dynamic/moving background based on a radial gradient with three colors like this:

The ideia is to have a center point like this one:

Dragging the animation and mixing the colors in more or less random ways.
I tried to search how to this with CSS but all I can find are simple static radial examples. What's the best way to approach this?

Without any code I doubt you will get any answers

First step is to figure our how to make 1 of those. Then you can rotate it or whatever. I have found it to look like a color wheel. I adapted code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/39399649/3807365

I've add offset to the hue as you get away from center for the spiral effect
I've incorporated mouse position into the calculations of the center.
It's a start you can tweak it further.



var mx = 0
var my = 0
var diameter = 200
var wheel
var can
var ctx
var rotate = 0


main()


function newEl(tag) {
  return document.createElement(tag)
}


function main() {
  wheel = makeWheel(diameter);
  wheel.addEventListener('mousemove', moveCenter);
  document.body.appendChild(wheel);
}


function hsv2rgb(hsv) {
  var h = hsv.hue,
    s = hsv.sat,
    v = hsv.val;
  var rgb, i, data = [];
  if (s === 0) {
    rgb = [v, v, v];
  } else {
    h = h / 60;
    i = Math.floor(h);
    data = [v * (1 - s), v * (1 - s * (h - i)), v * (1 - s * (1 - (h - i)))];
    switch (i) {
      case 0:
        rgb = [v, data[2], data[0]];
        break;
      case 1:
        rgb = [data[1], v, data[0]];
        break;
      case 2:
        rgb = [data[0], v, data[2]];
        break;
      case 3:
        rgb = [data[0], data[1], v];
        break;
      case 4:
        rgb = [data[2], data[0], v];
        break;
      default:
        rgb = [v, data[0], data[1]];
        break;
    }
  }
  return rgb;
};

function clamp(min, max, val) {
  if (val < min) return min;
  if (val > max) return max;
  return val;
}



function drawWheel(ctx) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height);

  var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, diameter, diameter);
  var maxRange = diameter / 2;

  for (var y = 0; y < diameter; y++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < diameter; x++) {
      var xPos = x - (diameter / 2) - mx;
      var yPos = (diameter - y) - (diameter / 2) - my;

      var polar = pos2polar({
        x: xPos,
        y: yPos
      });

      var hueOffset = 50 * (polar.len / maxRange);

      var hue = polar.ang + hueOffset;

      hue = hue % 360;
      while (hue < 0) {
        hue += 360;
      }

      var sat = clamp(0, 1, polar.len / (maxRange / 2));
      var val = clamp(0, 1, (maxRange - polar.len) / (maxRange / 2));

      var rgb = hsv2rgb({
        hue: hue,
        sat: sat,
        val: val
      });

      var index = 4 * (x + y * diameter);
      imgData.data[index + 0] = rgb[0] * 255;
      imgData.data[index + 1] = rgb[1] * 255;
      imgData.data[index + 2] = rgb[2] * 255;
      imgData.data[index + 3] = 255;
    }
  }
  ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
}

function makeWheel(diameter) {
  can = newEl('canvas');
  ctx = can.getContext('2d');
  can.width = diameter;
  can.height = diameter;

  drawWheel(ctx)
  return can;
}

function deg2rad(deg) {
  return (deg / 360) * (2 * Math.PI);
}

function rad2deg(rad) {
  return (rad / (Math.PI * 2)) * 360;
}

function pos2polar(inPos) {
  var vecLen = Math.sqrt((inPos.x + mx) * (inPos.x + mx) + (inPos.y + my) * (inPos.y + my));
  var something = Math.atan2(inPos.y, inPos.x) + deg2rad(rotate);
  while (something < 0)
    something += 2 * Math.PI;

  return {
    ang: rad2deg(something),
    len: vecLen
  };
}



function moveCenter(event) {
  var color = document.getElementById('color');

  mx = -diameter / 2 + event.offsetX;
  my = -1 * (-diameter / 2 + event.offsetY);
  var rx = mx / (diameter / 2)
  var ry = my / (diameter / 2)

  rotate = Math.sqrt(rx * rx + ry * ry) * 360
  color.innerText = "" + mx + ", " + my

}

function loop() {
  drawWheel(ctx)
  requestAnimationFrame(loop)
}
loop()
canvas {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
<div id="color" style="width: 200px; height: 50px; float: left;">Move mouse</div>



